# How to make cells of inner table to occupy the whole space of the outer table cell

Tags: css

I have a table inside a cell table. I want the table to occupy the whole space. It looks like the table is only occupying the center of the cell.

```
   <asp:ListView ID="EmployeeListView" runat="server">
      <LayoutTemplate>
           <table id="tblEmployee">
           </table>
      </LayoutTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
     <tr>
    <td>
    <table style = "width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse; padding: 0">
       <tr>
           <td class = "aprovGriditem">
               <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="3:15"></asp:Label>
           </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
           <td class = "aprovGridalt">
               <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="0:45"></asp:Label>
           </td>
       </tr>
    </table>
</td>
</tr>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

I want both cells of the inner table to occupy evenly the whole space of the outer cell, instead of concentring on the middle and leaving space around them.

```
#tblEmployee
{
  border-collapse: collapse;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
#tblEmployee th
{
 background-color: #BBC6E3;
 height: 25px;    
 }
 .aprovGriditem 
 {    
  border: 2px solid #BBC6E3;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  }
.aprovGridalt 
{
  background-color: #BBC6E3; 
  border: 2px solid #BBC6E3;
  padding: 0;
 width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Style your `table` with the following:

`height: 100%; width: 100%;`

To add those styles to your `table`, you can either use inline styles:

`<table style = "height: 100%; width: 100%;">`

Or give it a class (more preferable since you might want to use the same styling combination later):

`<table class = "bigtable">`

Then add this to your stylesheet:

```
.bigtable {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: + if you are having the empty cells, it will be better to put an empty space character inside `&nbsp;`, because in Firefox sometimes it's rendered not as in the other browsers

Comment: now the inner cells have occupy all the width but there are still space on the top and the bottom.

Comment: @Richard77 Can you provide your full HTML/CSS?

Comment: I've tried padding 0 and border-collapse = collapse, but I still get that extra-space on the top and on the bottom

Comment: I don't see the `height: 100%;` part in your CSS :)

Comment: See the edit. I even added style to the inner table, I'm still getting that extra space on the top and the bottom

Comment: Actually the extra space on the top and the bottom is happening inside the inner table. In fact, the cells are not occupying the whole space. It happening only with IE9

Answer (score 0):

Remove the body margin and padding:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

And wrap your table in a div that occupies all the space:

```
div {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```